# Difference equation with variable coefficients in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, linear-systems, differential-equation

Given the following difference equation

$$y[n]-\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)y[n-1] = n\cdot x[n]$$

How can we use MATLAB to solve it?

I know if the coefficients are constant we can simply use filter(b, a,x), but not sure how to do it with variable coefficients.

Comment: A loop would be a good idea... I mean, you can find $y[n]$ iteratively.

Comment: Thanks, any sample code/algorithm you could recommend?

Comment: Well, in Octave I would do this:

`y(1) = -1;`  

`x = randn(1,100);`  

`for n = 2:100`  
`y(n) = n*x(n) + (n/(n+1))*y(n-1);`  
`end`

Answer (score 1):

When $n=0$ you may need to know $y[-1]$. The current output $y(n)$ depends on the current input $x(n)$ and previous output $y(n-1)$ scaled.

Comment: Suppose I know that, How would I go about solving the system. I think that is my question.

Comment: The input sequence $x[n]$ is known then $y[n]$ can be computed with
$$y[n]= n\cdot x[n] + \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)y[n-1]$$

when $n=0$ use $y[-1]$ if available otherwise $y[-1]=0$


Do you need a MATLAB code example to solve above problem? But, I guess its not that complicated to implement.

Comment: Well for $n=0;\, y[0] = 0$ nevertheless.